# How do I change the order of my filter tags on my collection page?

Tags: shopify, liquid

Currently, my collection filter tags are displaying alphabetically. How do I go about changing this manually?

```
 {% if settings.collection_tags and collection.tags.size > 0 %}
    <nav class="filter-tag">
      <span class="mobile">{% unless current_tags %}{{ 'collections.sorting.title' | t }}{% endunless %}
            {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
              {% if current_tags contains tag %}
                {{ tag | capitalize }}
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </span>
```

Comment: Not sure what you trying to do. I suppose you want to filter a collection using product tags and you want to place them in a specific order. Is that it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need to do [something like this](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/product-tags-sort-order-56944#comment-214553) and create an array of tags in the order you want:

```
{% assign tags = 'Small, Medium, Large' | split: ',' %}

{% for t in tags %}  
    {% assign tag = t | strip %}
    {% if current_tags contains tag %}
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

See [here in the Shopify docs](https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/collections/filtering-a-collection-with-multiple-tag-drop-down#adding-the-code) for another example.